# Scala, ZIO - how to return value from Task?

Tags: scala, zio

I have a simple for-comprehension code:

```
def nameFormatter(request: SomeRequest) : FormattedData = {
      for {
        config <- ZIO.fromOption(configuration.get(request.name)).orElseFail( new Exception("Unknown config"))
        name = config.data.name.pipe(SomeName)
      } yield FormattedData(
        name,
        request.age
      )
    }
```

But this method returns:

```
ZIO[Any, Exception, FormattedData]
```

I would like to change this method to return only `FormattedData`, not the whole ZIO. Is it possible? Or maybe I should somehow read returned type and get value from it?

Comment: May I ask, why you want to return a plain value? Integration with a third-party service? Why are you using **ZIO** at all, because it comes from a third-partly library? Do you understand the purpose of an `IO` data type?

Comment: I want pure value, because I do not need effect here

Comment: So why even use **ZIO** in the first place? Why not just `configuration.get(request.name).map(config => FormattedData(name =  config.data.name.pipe(SomeName), age = request.age)` and return a `Option[FormattedData]`?

Answer (score 6):

ZIO makes it difficult to do this because it is unsafe and it defeats the purpose of using ZIO. You can tell from the type `ZIO[Any, Exception, FormattedData]` that it can fail with an `Exception` if you try to materialise the value.

If you really want to do it:

```scala
zio.Runtime.default.unsafeRun(nameFormatter(request))
```

otherwise you should be composing the rest of your code with the result of `nameFormatter(request)` and run it with something like:

```scala
import zio.{ExitCode, URIO, ZIO}

object Main extends zio.App {
  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] =
    (for {
      formattedData <- nameFormatter(request)
      // rest of your code
    } yield ()).exitCode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to use it is

```scala
nameFormatter(request).flatMap { formattedData =>
  // whatever you want to do with the returned value
  // ...
  // the rest of your program
}
```

or in a for comprehension:

```scala
for {
  formattedData <- nameFormatter(request)
  // rest of your program
} yield ()
```

This **DOES NOT** answer your question, however it's probably what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since ZIO 2.0, unsafe running an effect would be done like so:

```
zio.Runtime.default.unsafe.run(nameFormatter(request))
```

In order to work, you need to provide an implicit parameter `unsafe: zio.Unsafe`. This could be done like so:

```
Unsafe.unsafe(implicit u => zio.Runtime.default.unsafe.run(nameFormatter(request)))
```

See the documentation: https://zio.dev/reference/core/runtime/#running-a-zio-effect